# Java conditional issue

Tags: java, debugging, conditional-statements

No matter what I do this piece of code will never evaluate to true when the user inputs 1 at the console... I'm confused as to why it is evaluating to false.. any help is much appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Default 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the CS conversation game\n");
        System.out.println("Choose your game\n1)Hex to Decimal\n2)Binary to Decimal");
        Hex2Decimal PlayHex = new Hex2Decimal();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String GameSelection = null;
        try 
        {
            GameSelection = br.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(GameSelection == "1")
        {
            PlayHex.Play();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Should be `"1".equals(GameSelection)`, `==` compares references of objects, while `equals` compares content.

Also, the Java naming convention is to start variable names in lower case. (e.g. `gameSelection`, `playHex` etc.)

Comment: +1 for `"1".equals` and protecting against null pointer exception.

Comment: @amir I don't know if I would want that, honestly. If you're getting a null passed into a method that shouldn't have it, you want an exception. Otherwise, your code may be silently failing and you wouldn't know it.

Comment: @user1377384 If he solved your problem, how about you show Binyamin a little love and click the accepted answer checkmark on the left?

Comment: @corsiKa - I think it's a matter of style, I'm not a fanat of this style, but it comes handy in some situations.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar I never knew that .equals() actually checks for null values. Learned something new today :)

Comment: @corsiKa no this is something you want. If `GameSelection` is null you want to evaluate to `false` and not throw an exception which would terminate your application. You have to understand what `readLine()` is doing. If it throws an exception then `GameSelection` will remain null and your application will exit. I DOUBT this is what you want.

Comment: @Bartvbl it does if you do `"string".equals(foo)` and NOT `foo.equals("string")`. Just changing it around makes things a lot more safe when `foo` is `null`

Comment: @Bartvbl It doesn't "check" for null values.  In the example `"1".equals(whatever)`, `"1"` *cannot be* null.  Subtle but crucial difference.

Comment: @Amir no, it really isn't. If I have an exception that I didn't expect/count on, I want it to propagate up until it is handled. In this case it propagates to the JVM which terminates the application. I certainly don't want it to silently fail.

Comment: @TimPote I meant that the _parameter_ of the equals() function can be null without throwing a NullPointerException. I didn't know that that worked :) Of course a constant String like "1" is a non-null instance, and therefore safer to use.

Comment: @corsiKa NullPointerException is a runtime exception which you should avoid. Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

You need:

```
if(GameSelection.equals("1"))
```

instead of:

```
if(GameSelection == "1")
```

`==` is used to check if the 2 references refer to the same object in the memory, while `equals()` checks whether the 2 references refer to the same object in the memory **OR** to 2 different objects but with the same values (the 2 strings are equivalent).

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't have operator overloading.

You will have to use `.equals(...)`. Otherwise, you are comparing the reference address.

```
if(GameSelection.equals("1"))
{
   PlayHex.Play();
}
```